Confusion about MetadataPointer
Can someone explain the following please?
Why the mint account also needs the size of the metadata length(pack(metadata)), because the metadata is stored in another account, as I understand correctly, the mint account holds the the pointer to the metadata account, but is strange that the metadata pointer points then to the mint itself, cause it would be enough for the mint account to have a pointer directly to the metadata. (I assume to know the metadata of a mint, you point it from the mint to the metadata not vice-versa)
And the extensionType as NonTransferable is stored in the mint account right?
Also what I Don't understand, is how the createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction works, if the mint account is not initialised, then how the function works?
  const initMetadataPointerInstruction = createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
    mint.publicKey,
    payer.publicKey,
    mint.publicKey,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  );

  //Initialize the non transferable token mint

  const createNonTransferableMint = createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(
    mint.publicKey,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  );

  // 4. Initialize the mint
  const initMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mint.publicKey,
    decimals,
    payer.publicKey,
    null,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  );


I think there are many good articles available that provides detailed info on this topic.

https://solana.com/developers/courses/token-extensions/token-extensions-metadata
https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer#build-instructions
https://blog.offside.io/p/token-2022-security-best-practices-part-1#%C2%A7attention

The reason the mint and metadata cross-point to each other is the security, see https://solana.com/developers/courses/token-extensions/token-extensions-metadata
To avoid imitation mints claiming to be a stablecoin, a client can now check whether the mint and the metadata point to each other.

